# AppDelegate Access

Tags: iphone

For the old version xcode/ios, I used:

```
appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

to access AppDelegate

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


 @property (nonatomic,retain) AppDelegate *appDelegate;



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end

//-----

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface DetailController : UIViewController{
}
  @property (nonatomic,retain) AppDelegate *appDelegate;



@end
```

but in ios5 AppDelegate change from NSObject to UIRepsonder

Is it possible to access the AppDelegate?

Welcome ant comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not know what misconception you have in your mind. But What I use in iOS 5 application development is still same.

As per your comment above you said you wrote this code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@property (nonatomic,retain) AppDelegate *appDelegate;  // This line is unnecessary
```

You do not have to create property for AppDelegate class's object. Just include this line in your .m file where you want to access global variable:

```
// Create an AppDelegate variable in your MapViewScreen @interface
AppDelegate *appDelegate;

#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation MapViewScreen

- (void)viewDidLoad  
{
    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

**P.S.**: As Michael pointed out **[UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** inherits from **[NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** so you do not have to worry. Everything's the same.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to change anything for iOS 5. The [UIResponder class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) inherits from NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the same thing you were using to access appDelegate..

Comment: I wrote:
 
#import "AppDelegate.h"
 

  @property (nonatomic,retain) AppDelegate *appDelegate;